# What is the minimum amount of metadata is needed to stream only video using libx264 to encode at the server and libffmpeg to decode at the client?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, libx264

I want to stream video (no audio) from a server to a client. I will encode the video using libx264 and decode it with ffmpeg. I plan to use fixed settings (at the very least they will be known in advance by both the client and the server). I was wondering if I can avoid wrapping the compressed video in a container format (like mp4 or mkv).

Right now I am able to encode my frames using x264_encoder_encode. I get a compressed frame back, and I can do that for every frame. What extra information (if anything at all) do I need to send to the client so that ffmpeg can decode the compressed frames, and more importantly how can I obtain it with libx264. I assume I may need to generate NAL information (x264_nal_encode?). Having an idea of what is the minimum necessary to get the video across, and how to put the pieces together would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the minimum amount of information are the NAL units from each frame, this will give me a raw h264 stream. If I were to write this to a file, I could watchit using VLC if adding a .h264
I can also open such a file using ffmpeg, but if I want to stream it, then it makes more sense to use RTSP, and a good open source library for that is Live555: http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/

In their FAQ they mention how to send the output from your encoder to live555, and there is source for both a client and a server. I have yet to finish coding this, but it seems like a reasonable solution